# Working with Jenkins Credentials plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I am a newbie to jenkins.I was working on jenkins credential plugin.I have installed the credential plugin and managed the credentials.

So now I want to invoke the credentials but I don't know how to work with it .So what all steps I need to follow to work with jenkins credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the credentials under Global Credentials. These credentials should be listed throughout Jenkins and can be used anywhere accordingly.

For ex, to use the credentials(which you just created), go to Job Configuration > Source Code Management > Enter the repository URL and credentials should appear under the drop-down for Credentials.

Comment: This works if we are using subversion repository. I am working with Integrity and it is not working with it. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Which Integrity are you working with? Jenkins has plugins for most of the integrity systems and these plugins have their own way of specifying credentials(text boxes within the plugin).